# SDL 2 Showing an image on screen via a SpriteManager, getting a pointer break

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm entirely new to SDL 2 , and I'm hoping to find some help with making my very first proper program for a class in it. We've been provided with some code already for use in this project, which is why I'm not simply using a BlitSurface function to make this solution. If that is indeed the better solution, I'll switch over to that. This is part of a State to be used when the program runs, showing a title image.

I am getting a break error due to a pointer issue in the following code:

```
void MenuState::Enter()
{
//Is to load the title image used for the State
Sprite* extBackgroundSprite = met_extSystem.met_pointextSpriteManager-     >CreateSprite("../assets/Testimage1.bmp" , 0 , 0  , 768 , 1024);
}
```

Which refers to a Sprite made by a SpriteManager class and CreateSprite function, as seen here:

```
Sprite * SpriteManager::CreateSprite(const std::string & point_stringFilePath, int point_intX, int point_intY, int point_intWidth, int point_intHeight)
{
auto iter = met_arraypointextTextures.find(point_stringFilePath); //breaks here
if (iter == met_arraypointextTextures.end())
    //If the iterator cannot locate the sprite we need in our already loaded memory, 
    //it needs to be loaded into our map to create pointers 
{
    SDL_Surface* extSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(point_stringFilePath.c_str());
    SDL_Texture* extTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(met_pointextRenderer, extSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(extSurface);
    met_arraypointextTextures.insert(std::pair<std::string, SDL_Texture*>(point_stringFilePath, extTexture));
    iter = met_arraypointextTextures.find(point_stringFilePath);

}
//Creates the sprite, adds a new index point via pushback
Sprite* extSprite = new Sprite(iter->second, point_intX, point_intY, point_intWidth, point_intHeight);
met_arraypointextSprites.push_back(extSprite);
return extSprite;
}
```

I hope this is enough information and code to present my problem. If not, let me know! And thank you in advance.

Comment: What is a "pointer issue"? Might as well be uninitialized `met_extSystem.met_pointextSpriteManager`.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it might be. What happens is the program breaks specifically at the point mentioned, which it might do if it is uninitialized. But I don't quite know how to fix that issue.

Comment: How do you initialize `met_extSystem.met_pointextSpriteManager`? ...

Comment: Well, it's declared in an Interface class as such: struct System
{
 int met_intScreenWidth;
 int met_intScreenHeight;
 SpriteManager* met_pointextSpriteManager;
 DrawManager* met_pointextDrawManager;
 InputManager* met_pointextInputManager; //May need to work differently, check with other programmers
};
class IState
{
public:
 virtual ~IState() {};
 virtual void Enter() {};
 virtual bool Update(float point_floatDeltaTime) = 0;
 virtual void Exit() {};
 virtual void Draw() = 0;
 virtual IState* NextState() = 0;
};

Comment: As for the spritemanager itself, I'm not entirely sure it is initialized properly, now that you mention it. It's mentioned in the h file , but never declared.

Comment: But even trying to initialize it to a nullpointer now, doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure something like that was ever done in the example we were given.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was impossible to solve with the information I provided. The pointer did indeed need to be initialized, but with arguments found in the constructor, which I had not provided here.